# Querying Azure Diagnostic table storages

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-diagnostics

We are storing our Windows/Linux VM metrics and logs into Azure diagnostics storage account for long term retention. We keep this data  in Log Analytics as well but being cost conscious we keep only the minimal essential set and for 1 month. However it seems there is no way to efficiently query the Table storage data when we need it - e.g. checking historical cpu usage for a particular machine over a specific period in the past, or checking the logs captured during that period. The partition key and row key is highly convoluted with some very basic help available for the WAD tables schema while none exist for LinuxsyslogVer2v0 table schema. I was curious if anyone else using the diagnostic logs table storage for any querying/reporting? If so how do you query these for a specific host and time period? I can do a querying using non primary/row key but besides being time consuming it will cost a hell eventually considering that will be a table scan. Really appreciate any advice.

[image: Syslog table sample row (partial view)]

Comment: Please edit your question and include a sample record from the table.

Comment: @GauravMantri, have added a partial snapshot of one row. I am not sure if it will help. I couldn't find a better way to share the row details. Actually this brings me back to my original question -shouldn't this be part of standard MS documentation?

Comment: I really needed to see the partition key value :).

Comment: sorry, here is an example: 0000000000000000000___0637660340400000000

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using **Azure Data Explorer** (ADX) for your long-term storage solution. It allows for KQL queries on your long-term data and is the preferred method for keeping log/security data past the default for services like LogA and Sentinel.

The pricing page for ADX can be a bit confusing and there is a website to help you estimate costs here: https://dataexplorer.azure.com/AzureDataExplorerCostEstimator.html

By default, logs ingested into Azure Sentinel are stored in Azure Monitor Log Analytics. This article explains how to reduce retention costs in Azure Sentinel by sending them to Azure Data Explorer for long-term retention.

Storing logs in Azure Data Explorer reduces costs while retains your ability to query your data, and is especially useful as your data grows. For example, while security data may lose value over time, you may be required to retain logs for regulatory requirements or to run periodic investigations on older data.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/store-logs-in-azure-data-explorer?tabs=adx-event-hub

Comment: Appreciate your response. In our case it is VM logs and metrics collected via VM diagnostics agent. Note: I should have added to my question: We are capturing minimal essential log data to log analytics e.g. critical, err and warn to keep cost low, while we are using diagnostic logs to capture the complete logs from VMs. So we cannot use Log analytics export since it is not capturing those data in the first place. Hence what other alternatives to capture the data into data explorer in place of storage account? Is there anyway to route diagnostic logs to a more convenient queriable store?